# Does anybody know what is gvfsd-http?

Tags: linux, networking, fedora

gvfsd-http exists in Fedora, Ubuntu, and several other distros. Does anybody know what this process is used for? There is no information on the net, other than "gnome virtual file system".

What is it used for?

If it is not mandatory, how to get rid of it?

Sometimes I see connections like this:

```
tcp        1      0 192.168.1.3:45229       50.17.249.143:80        CLOSE_WAIT  5463/gvfsd-http
```

As you see the process is gvfsd-http. The IP address belongs to: cz-usa.com, a gun company. I had nothing to do with this website. Any ideas what is this process doing?

Comment: @Goddard The problem here is creating duplicate questions without first searching thoroughly. The OP hasn't explained in which way his question differs from the one I linked in my "horrible comment", so, as far as I'm concerned, this is a duplicate. Have a look there and if that information is not helpful in your case, then create a new question with your specific problem on the appropriate site and some people might volunteer to help you.

Comment: @MihaiTodor I'm not saying the question didn't deserve to be closed, or the person failed to do what they should of done.  What I am saying is in no way should any stack exchange user ever suggest some one to "Use Google"... When I used duckduckgo it lead me here.  Your comment correctly links the user, but I agree we should suggest the correct exchange and then suggest using the sites search feature.  Not Google or DuckDuckGo, or Yahoo...or what ever search engine is my point.

Comment: @Goddard Unfortunately, the StackOverflow search engine still has a long way to go until it beats Google, so yeah, people will have trouble locating what they need if they don't use Google by default. Most of us do expect people who ask questions to do their homework first, so if you don't want to use Google for it, then perhaps you should lower your expectations.

Comment: @MihaiTodor The stack exchange search engine works great.  I think you mean a Search engine by default.  Not just Google as Bing, Yahoo, DuckDuckGo, and many others work just as good and sometimes better.  Of course people expect others to do their home work, but that doesn't mean other sites.  It means only stack exchange sites.  That is my point.

Comment: I've Googled a server to death, and cannot find an answer. Even the homepage doesn't seem to know what it's for.

Answer (score 11):

This is a gvfs module for http support. It is used for example when you drag an image from the browser to the nautilus window.

Comment: This doesn't tell us a great deal either.